# Salesforce Polymer Mobile UI on Android Chrome gives blank page

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, cordova

I saw this article [Secure, Offline, Cross-Platform Apps with Salesforce Mobile SDK and Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/cross-platform-apps-salesforce-mobile-sdk-web-components.html)
and found it very interesting,  when I try the sample application
[Heroku Hosted Version of the Canonical Sample App](https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/) on Chrome on the desktop it works fine, but when I go to the same page with Chrome on an Android phone (I tried 2 different phones) I get a blank page.

Using Chrome remote debugging tool I can see that the error occurs in cordova.force.js, full error below:

```
Exception caught during observer callback: ReferenceError: Connection is not defined
at Object.deviceIsOnline (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/dependencies/mobilesdk-shared/libs/cordova.force.js:164:45)
at Object.SFDC.isOnline (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/elements/force-app/force-app.js:31:85)
at force-ui-search.Polymer.computeQuery (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/elements/force-ui-search/force-ui-search.html:53:22)
at force-ui-search.g.invokeMethod (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/dependencies/polymer/polymer.js:13:25932)
at force-ui-search.g.notifyPropertyChanges (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/dependencies/polymer/polymer.js:13:24037)
at Object.x.report_ (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/dependencies/polymer/polymer.js:12:18266)
at Object.S.check_ (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/dependencies/polymer/polymer.js:12:22604)
at c (https://sfdc-sobject-editor.herokuapp.com/dependencies/polymer/polymer.js:12:12173)
```

the line giving an error in cordova.force.js is the first return line below:

```
    if (typeof connType !== 'undefined') {
        // Cordova's connection object.  May be more accurate?
        return (connType && connType != Connection.NONE && connType != Connection.UNKNOWN);
    } else {
        // Default to browser facility.
        return navigator.onLine;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works on the Android WebView, not Android Chrome. Android Chrome has `navigator.onLine` but not `window.Connection`, which is a Cordova object.

The [new code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/libs/cordova.force.js#L162) fixes the existence check:

```
    if (typeof connType !== 'undefined' && window.Connection) {
        // Cordova's connection object.  May be more accurate?
        return (connType && connType != Connection.NONE && connType != Connection.UNKNOWN);
    } else {
        // Default to browser facility.
        return navigator.onLine;
    }
};
```

> Android 2.2 introduces the navigation.connection interface but it does not work properly in WebView.  So in order to get the proper connection information we had to implement our own connection interface which is accessible at navigator.network.connection.

**References**

- [SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/cordova.force.js at master · forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared · GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/libs/cordova.force.js#L162)